# Ruby script does not work with weird errors about highline library

Tags: ruby, highline

I have the following Ruby script:

```
begin 
      puts "What is the password? "
      the_pass = ask("") { |q| q.echo = "*" }
end while the_pass == nil || the_pass == "\n" || the_pass == ""
```

And it fails when I hit Enter:

> undefined method `default_external' for REXML::Encoding:Module
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline.rb:621:in`
>   say'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline.rb:914:in
>   `get_response'
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/highline-1.6.19/lib/highline.rb:259:in`
>   ask'

Looks like it fails when validating the input for `the_pass`, but I cannot understand the error, how are they related?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad error handling in the `HighLine` gem for Ruby < 1.9.

The offending line (identified by your error message) is:

```
statement.force_encoding(Encoding.default_external) if defined?(Encoding) && Encoding.default_external
```

You can handle this by either:

1. Removing any `include REXML` commands in your script. This will keep `REXML::Encoding` from being associated with `Encoding`.
2. Adding the following line somewhere early in your script:

   `REXML::Encoding.instance_eval { def default_external; false; end }`

   This line will prevent the missing method error and will prevent `HighLine` from trying to force encoding where it shouldn't.